# Validation of an XML and DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I have a problem with my XML and DTD and I can't understand what it is.
Normally, my xml is well formed:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE corpus SYSTEM "POUR.dtd">

<corpus>
  <position type="pour">
    <discours auteur="Aécio Neves" id="1" date="25/08/2016" lieu="Senado 
  Federal">blablabla</discours>
  </position>
</corpus>
```

And I did my DTD too:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!ELEMENT corpus (discours)+>
<!ELEMENT discours (auteur, date, lieu)>
<!ATTLIST discours id CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT auteur (#CDATA)>
<!ELEMENT date (#CDATA)>
<!ELEMENT lieu (#CDATA)>
```

My validation: xmllint POUR.xml --dtdvalid POUR.dtd --noout

Errors:

```
POUR.dtd:7: parser error : ContentDecl : Name or '(' expected
<!ELEMENT auteur (#CDATA)>
              ^
POUR.dtd:7: parser error : expected '>'
<!ELEMENT auteur (#CDATA)>
              ^
POUR.dtd:7: parser error : Content error in the external subset
<!ELEMENT auteur (#CDATA)>
```

Can anybody help me? Thank you! :-)

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of issues. I concentrate on the one you're seeing.

With

```
<!ELEMENT auteur (whatever here)>
```

you're declaring an element <auteur>. To declare an element that only contains text, you need to declare content #PCDATA:

```
<!ELEMENT auteur (#PCDATA)>
```

However your XML contains no <auteur> element. auteur is an attribute to element <discours>. Therefore the proper way to declare it is to add it to the list of attributes declared in ATTLIST. And there, since it is an attribute, the correct type to indicate is CDATA.